# VMWare Player - swapping to disk more if more memory allocated

Tags: development-environment, vmware, virtual-machine

Windows XP as base OS.  Laptop has 4GB RAM and 2*2.2GHz cores.  About 3 year old laptop

Am using Windows7 in VMWare Player.  If I allocate more than 1GB of RAM to the Win7 machine in the VMWare player settings it goes so slow, and is continually swapping to disk.

I've turned off all Win7 processor intensive stuff.

http://www.computingunleashed.com/speed-up-windows-7-ultimate-guide-to.html

http://www.computingunleashed.com/list-of-services-in-windows-7-that-can.html

The base OS only reports using aboiut 144MB of RAM to the player.  Very weird.

I'm using 2 virtual disks:  20GB SCSI for c:\ and 25GB SCSI for data f:\

**Problem**:  How to tweak Win7 VMware (ie VS2010, Sql2008R2) well on an older laptop.  Or use something else?

Comment: Am trying VirtualBox now instead of VMWare Player.. looking much more responsive so far.

Comment: Yep, VirtualBox works better for me.  Top tip is to turn off screensaver power mode in Win7 as this crashed my vm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by default vmware player uses  file as memory.
Read this for more info & fix
http://communities.vmware.com/thread/46122

Comment: The link requires you to log in. It would be helpful to add more information in the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this **for all your VMs**, you may just add/append following two lines:

```
 prefvmx.minVmMemPct = 100
 mainMem.useNamedFile = "false"
```

... inside the following VMware-wide configuration file:

> C:/ProgramData/VMware/VMware Workstation/`config.ini` (or sometimes `settings.ini`)

The first line sets the [percentage of configured VM memory that should fit into the host memory](http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2015/02/quick-tip-how-to-enable-memory-overcommitment-in-vmware-fusion.html) and the second (as already shown in the prior answer) disables default file-based memory usage.

---

If you want to apply this **to a *specific* VM only**, in order to not alter *general* VMware configuration, adding the following line to the VM's **`*.vmx`** file *may* be an alternative:

```
 hard-disk.hostBuffer = "disabled"
```